# How to pass parameters to another php page without leaving the page

Tags: jquery

`<a href="index.php?page=absent&id='.base64_encode($result['id']).'&subject='.base64_encode($subject).'">Absent</a>`
I want send these parameters to absent.php page without refreshing

Comment: Have you tried [jQuery.post](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)?

Comment: @Markus rather `jQuery.get`, as there is query string used, but using query strings to post data is a bad practice because of CSRF.